# How can I just make bottomappbar's top border color orange?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have this BottomAppBar and I want to make it a transparent background while keeping the top border color orange.

Is there any way that I can do this?

------ EDIT

EXAMPLE 1)
[image]

EXAMPLE 2)
[image]

CODE)

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2))),
      child:..... )
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this by using the Container widget with a transparent color and a decoration property that has a BoxDecoration with a solid border and an orange color

Comment: How can I make the curve like that? I could only made them straight line

Comment: Container(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.orange,
        width: 2,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: BottomAppBar(...),
)

Comment: can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: As you can see, it becomes a straight line. I want to make it curved in the middle like the part I marked with white color on example 1